# Не отображается метка после выбора пункта листа в java swing

Tags: java, swing

//Пример использования простого списка JList

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

class HelpSwing implements ListSelectionListener {

 JList<String> jlst;
 JLabel jlab, jlab1;
 JScrollPane jscrlp; 

 String menu[] = { "1. if", "2. switch", "3. for", "4. while",
                "5. do-while", "6. break", "7.continue"};

 HelpSwing() {

  JFrame jfrm = new JFrame("JList Demo");

  jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

  jfrm.setSize(400,300);

  jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  jlst = new JList<String>(menu);

  jlst.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);

  jscrlp = new JScrollPane(jlst);

  jscrlp.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 150));

  jlab = new JLabel("Справка: ");
  jlab1 = new JLabel("Выберите пункт меню");

  jlst.addListSelectionListener(this);

  jfrm.add(jlab);
  jfrm.add(jscrlp);
  jfrm.add(jlab1);

  jfrm.setVisible(true);
 }

 public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent le) {

   int idx = jlst.getSelectedIndex();

   if(idx != -1) {
    switch(idx) {
     case '0':
        jlab1.setText("<html>Оператор if:<br>if(условие) оператор;<br>else оператор:</html>");
        break;
     case '1':
        jlab1.setText("<html>Оператор switch:<br>switch(выражение) {<br>case константа:<br>последовательность операторов<br>break;<br>// ...<br>}</html>");
        break;
     case '2':
        jlab1.setText("<html>Oпepaтop for:<br>for(инициaлизaция; условие; итерация)<br>оператор;</html>");
        break;
     case '3':
        jlab1.setText("<html>Oпepaтop while:<br>while(ycлoвиe) оператор;</html>");
        break;
     case '4':
        jlab1.setText("<html>Oпepaтop do-while:<br>do {<br>оператор;<br>} while (условие);</html>");
        break;
     case '5':
        jlab1.setText("<html>Oпepaтop break:<br>break; или break метка;</html>");
        break;
     case '6':
        jlab1.setText("<html>Oпepaтop continue:<br>continue; или continue метка;;</html>");
        break;
    }
   } else jlab1.setText("Please choose a item");

 }

public static void main(String args[]) {
  //Создать фрейм в потоке диспетчеризации событий
  SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      new HelpSwing();
    }
  });
}
}
```

Comment: Тип idx - int, а case у вас тип char, итого, например, (int)'0' равен 48, условия не выполнится.

Comment: @RuslanP. спасибо, помогли